# How to remove programatically created controls one by one?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i wrote some code for creating controls dynamically. this code is working fine, now i want to remove control one by one on button click. so help me how can i do this ?

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Label label = new Label();
            int count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count));
            label.Size = new Size(40, 20);
            label.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
            label.Text = "label " + (count + 1);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label);

            TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count;
            textbox.Location = new Point(60, 25 * count);
            textbox.Size = new Size(80, 20);
            textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
            textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);

            Button button = new Button();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().Count;
            button.Location = new Point(150, 25 * count);
            button.Size = new Size(60, 20);
            button.Name = "button_" + (count + 1);
            button.Text = "Button " + (count + 1);
            //button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
            panel1.Controls.Add(button);

    }
```

Comment: Use the Tag property to mark your dinamically created controls. Then when you want to remove them use the Controls collection to retrieve every control with your Tag property. At this point a simple reverse loop will allow you to remove the controls from the collection

Answer (score 2):

First, create the list of dynamic controls and add your programmatically created controls to it. Then you can remove controls one by one.

```
    private List<Control> dynamicControls = new List<Control>();

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label label = new Label();
        //...
        dynamicControls.Add(label);

        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        //...
        dynamicControls.Add(textbox);

        Button button = new Button();
        //...
        dynamicControls.Add(button);
    }

    public void RemoveDynamicControls()
    {
        if (dynamicControls.Count > 0)
        {
            var control = dynamicControls[0];

            if (panel1.Controls.Contains(control))
            {
                dynamicControls.Remove(control);
                panel1.Controls.Remove(control);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Disposing the control is really important to release handle and unmanaged resources.

Comment: ..Unless he wants to re-use them later ;-)